# htaccess - Can this be done? (Nested IfModules)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect to a URL if a test for a module passes.

Something like this (Which doesn't seem to work for me.)

Perhaps this just isn't possible. Anyone?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/mod_gzip/?$ mod_gzip-is-enabled.php
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

Nested `<IfModule>` containers are not your problem (yes, this is possible). (But is the outer `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` container necessary?)

Your problem is the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^/mod_gzip/?$`:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/mod_gzip/?$ mod_gzip-is-enabled.php
> ```

This will never match in a per-directory `.htaccess` context, because of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. You need to remove it, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^mod_gzip/?$ mod_gzip-is-enabled.php [L]
```

In order to match a requested URL of the form `/mod_gzip/` (or `/mod_gzip`).

In per-directory `.htaccess` files, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against is less the *directory-prefix*, which notably ends with a slash. So the URL-path that is matched never starts with a slash. (This differs from when the directives are used in a server or virtualhost context.)

Also, you should probably include the `L` flag in case you have other directives.

Comment: "But is the outer <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> container necessary?"

Well I figured it was because if mod_rewrite.c isn't available then Rewrite atempts would fail(?)

I tried your code but visiting [domain].com/mod_gzip is just redirecting to / as if mod_gzip-is-enabled.php doesn't exist (Which it does.)

Comment: Whether the outer `<IfModule>` that checks for mod_rewrite is required is dependent on whether the ability to rewrite the URL is mandatory or not? If you are OK with the process _silently_ failing regardless of whether mod_gzip is enabled then keep the check for mod_rewrite. If you are seeing a "redirect to `/`" then _something else_ is triggering that - there is no "redirect" here, it's an _internal rewrite_. (If `mod_gzip-is-enabled.php` didn't exist and this directive was executed then you'd expect to see a 404.) Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file (or server config)?